# Rails: How to use ActionMailer by itself?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I am creating an app that will be used to send emails. I don't need to use regular mailers and view templates because I will simply be receiving the data that will be used to generate the email. However, I assume that there are some benefits to using `ActionMailer` instead of interacting with `SMTP` directly. I ran into issues while trying to instantiate a new instance of `ActionMailer::Base`. How can I use `ActionMailer` by itself without having to define a new class that extends `ActionMailer::Base`?

Comment: The question is a bit confusing. You say you are creating a RESTful API to send emails. Is the rails app that is handling the RESTful API also responsible for sending the emails?

Comment: You're right, sorry. I've updated the question and took out the part about REST because it had nothing to do with my real question.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to extend ActionMailer::Base? That's how it's intended to work.

Comment: @tybro0103 because I don't need views and I don't need different types of emails defined as different methods. All I need is the `mail()` method which I can pass all the values that are defined on an email.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The underlying functionality for ActionMailer is provided by the [mail gem](https://github.com/mikel/mail). This allows you to send mail very simply, e.g:

```
Mail.deliver do
  from     'me@test.lindsaar.net'
  to       'you@test.lindsaar.net'
  subject  'Here is the image you wanted'
  body     File.read('body.txt')
  add_file :filename => 'somefile.png', :content => File.read('/somefile.png')
end
```

It supports delivery by all the same methods that ActionMailer does.

Comment: Can we use placeholders in mail body, by using mail gem.

Comment: So presumably you can just use this in a Ruby script without Rails?

Answer (score 2):

This is a most basic solution. You have to change smtp settings and the hard coded values to variables etc. This way you do not need to use a View. If you still want to use ERB I suggest you check out [Railscast 206](http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3).

Just change this code, put it in a file like "test_email.rb" and call it with `ruby test_email.rb`

```
require 'action_mailer'

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => "gmail.com",
  :user_name            => "testuser123",
  :password             => "secret",
  :authentication       => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}

class TestMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "testuser123@gmail.com"

  # def somemethod()
  #   mail(:to => "John Doe <john@example.com>", :subject => "TEST", :body => "HERE WE GO!!!")
  # end

  def mail(args)
    super
  end
end

# TestMailer.somemethod().deliver
TestMailer.mail(:to => "John Doe <john@example.com>", :subject => "TEST", :body => "HERE WE GO!!!")
```

Comment: This is the type of thing I am already doing. I have a generic mailer with a generic "prepare" method. I would like to do something like call `mail()` directly since that is all I am using.

Comment: Ok I changed my code to be more generic. This is what you want, but not the way you suggested it. I know it has a bit of overhead but it follows your specification. You can override everything, no views etc. The default from is irrelevant as you can add your own in mail().

Answer (score 2):

Ah, I think I better understand now. Basically you're looking for a simple one-liner similar to php's mail(), right?

If so, ActionMailer isn't making sense to you because it really isn't the right tool for this job.

I think the winner for you is a ruby gem called Pony:
https://github.com/benprew/pony

example:

```
Pony.mail(:to => 'you@example.com', :from => 'me@example.com', :subject => 'hi', :body => 'Hello there.')
```

Comment: I find ActionMailer outside Rails to be verbosive and slightly cumbersome to use. I am also using Pony outside in my Ruby (but not Rails) projects.